# Problems with negative numbers

Tags: c, pic

I Have this "simple" code.

```
union
{
    unsigned int res;
    char         bytes[2];
} ADC;

char ADC_num[5];
float temprature;

void vis_temp (void)        //  Show temp..
{ 
    signed int l, length;
    unsigned int rem;

    GO_nDONE=1;             // initiate conversion on the channel 0   

    while (GO_nDONE) continue;

    ADC.bytes[0]=ADRESL;
    ADC.bytes[1]=ADRESH;

    utoa(ADC_num, ADC.res, 10);

    temprature = (float) ADC.res * 478.1 / 1024;
    temprature = temprature - 50.0;

    l = (signed int) temprature;
    temprature -= (float) l;  
    rem = (unsigned int)(temprature* 1e1);

    sprintf(&ADC_num, "%i.%u", l, rem);
```

When reading `ADC_res` (voltage on pin, temperature sensor) that temperature is 0 degree or under then program writes "0.65500" instead of "-3.5" or similar.
I should have declared the right as signed and unsigned int.
Any hints to fix it, or have an other way of converting it.

Comment: could you please paste the definition of your ADC structure?

Comment: We can't answer this accurately with so little information. Don't make us guess. Please present a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temprature = (float) ADC.res * 478.1 / 1024;
temprature = temprature - 50.0;
```

Suppose now `temprature` has a negative value `-x.yz`.

```
l = (signed int) temprature;
```

Now `l = -x`, and

```
temprature -= (float) l;
```

`temprature = -x.yz - (-x) = -0.yz`.

```
rem = (unsigned int)(temprature* 1e1);
```

Multiply with 10, and convert to `unsigned int`. Usually, that results in undefined behaviour (6.3.1.4 (1)):

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.<sup>61)</sup>
>
> <sup>61)</sup> The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type is converted to unsigned type need not be performed when a value of real floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the range of portable real floating values is `(−1, Utype_MAX+1)`.

But converting the negative value to `unsigned int` would produce the wrong result anyway, even if the remaindering operation is done, what you want is the absolute value, so you should convert

```
rem = (unsigned int)fabsf(temprature * 1e1);
```

there.

Comment: No good `Error   [499] ; 0. undefined symbol:
 _fabsf(Temp.obj) 
`

Comment: `fabsf` is part of the standard library. I suppose your embedded compiler doesn't support it, which is allowed for freestanding implementations. So use `if (temprature) < 0) temprature = -temprature;` to get the absolute value.

Comment: Yes, the integer part (`l`) should be negative if the temperature is. You take the absolute value after the `temprature -= l;`, so that the fractional part is non-negative. Consider `t = -3.125`. After `t -= l;` you're left with `t = -0.125`. Now, you want to print `-3.1`, so you want `rem = (unsigned int)(0.125 * 10);`.

Comment: ` 
      l = (signed int)temprature;
      temprature -= l;//(float)l;
            rem = (unsigned int)(temprature* 10);
          if (temprature<0)rem = rem*-1;
        
             sprintf(&ADC_num, "%i.%u", l, rem);`  That works, thank for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be coming from the call to the `utoa()` function.

The `utoa()` function prototype is generally as follow

```
char * utoa(unsigned int n, char * buffer, int radix);
```

In your code you have inverted the two first parameters. You are modifying the ADC structure through this call. I am curious how this could ever be compiled without any error? Any decent compiler would complain about passing an argument which is not a pointer type.

Try with the following

```
utoa(ADC.res, ADC_num, 10);
```

Comment: Changing them give this error  212.13 illegal conversion of integer to pointer

Comment: What compiler do you use? How is the `utoa()` function prototype defined in your compiler headers? You may try the following: `utoa(ADC.res, &ADC_num[0], 10);` but I can't see why it is complaining if the prototype is the common one

Comment: HI-TECH C Compiler for PIC10/12/16 MCUs (Lite Mode)  V9.83
Copyright (C) 2011 Microchip Technology Inc.

Comment: in my docs the utoa is `char * utoa(char * buf, unsigned val, int base);`

Comment: Ok this is possible as the `utoa()` function is not part of the ISO C standard functions. PIC compilers are definitely exotic compilers...